# Specific kernel version needed by elrepo on CentOS5

Tags: linux, centos, linux-kernel, repository

I can not install `elrepo` in an updated CentOS 5 system.

This is the error we get when we tried to install it:

```
[root@static ~]# rpm -Uvh http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-5-5.el5.elrepo.noarch.rpm
Retrieving http://www.elrepo.org/elrepo-release-5-5.el5.elrepo.noarch.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        kernel = 2.6.18 is needed by elrepo-release-5-5.el5.elrepo.noarch
```

And this is the version of the kernel running on the system:

```
[root@static ~]# uname -r
2.6.32-042stab078.28
```

Could you please explain us why we can't complete the installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe error you get stated that the `elrepo` release you are trying to install requires that exact version of the kernel.

The kernel your system is running is more recent, so either you can downgrade the kernel itself to the version required, or you have to look for an `elrepo` release compatible with your current kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

now :

```
[root@static ~]# rpm -Uvh kernel-2.6.18-417.el5.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm
warning: kernel-2.6.18-417.el5.centos.plus.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID e8562897: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
        mkinitrd >= 4.2.21-1 is needed by kernel-2.6.18-417.el5.centos.plus.x86_64
        kernel >= 2.6.32-642 is needed by util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.24.el6_8.1.x86_64
        kernel >= 2.6.32-642 is needed by (installed) util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.24.el6_8.1.x86_64
```

:|

Comment: Unfortunately, downgrading a kernel may require the downgrade of some other packages as well, as you have just noticed. Is there any other version of `elrepo` available?